# How to calculate the offset value for Jetty 8 web socket sendMessageMethod

Tags: scala, websocket, jetty, arrays

I have a project where a proxy sends Base64 encoded messages to the server.  The server then decodes the messages into a byte array and sends to the client.  The Jetty 8 [WeboScoket.Connection](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocket.Connection.html#sendMessage%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) sendMessage(data, offset, length) method expects an offset.

Question how does one determine this offset when decoding from base64?

Also is it okay to assume that the length parameter is the converted byte array's length?

```
def onMessage(message:String) {
      println("From client: " + message)
      val decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(message)
      println("Decoded and sent to the client: " + decoded)
      serverSocket.connection.sendMessage(decoded, offset???, decoded.length)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: It's an offset into `decoded`, supporting the case that only a part of an array is to be sent. Here, this parameter probably should be `0`.

---

The link you've put into your message points to API v7, not 8.

Grep coding for [org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.connection](http://grepcode.com/search?query=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.connection&start=0&entity=type&n=), I've followed [this one](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-websocket/8.1.14.v20131031/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocket.java#WebSocket.Connection) in jetty-websocket. Then you can find types implementing that method -- e.g. [WebSocketConnectionD00](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-websocket/8.1.14.v20131031/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketConnectionD00.java#234). You see your data mysteriously disappearing into the `addFrame` method of another interface, `WebSocketGenerator`. Now [here's finally the real meat](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-websocket/8.1.14.v20131031/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455.java#74).

This is pretty low-level here, you can find the data being put into yet another abstraction:

```
    private Buffer _buffer;
    ...
    _buffer.put(content, offset + (payload - remaining), chunk);
```

[One more down](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/8.1.14.v20131031/org/eclipse/jetty/io/Buffer.java#Buffer.put%28byte%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29), and here's the info. Wait... no. Either grepcode is showing wrong data here or the devs copy/pasted the comments from the `void put(byte b)` to the two methods below, just adapting the comment on the returned value.

[One more down](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/8.1.14.v20131031/org/eclipse/jetty/io/AbstractBuffer.java#AbstractBuffer.poke%28int%2Cbyte%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29), and you finally see what's happening:

```
    System.arraycopy(b, offset, dst_array, index, length);
```

, where `b` is the `decoded` byte[]. Unfortunately, using grepcode, one cannot dive into that implementation.

---

Note that I don't use Jetty. Just wanted to look into some other code...